# Automated speed tests with a curl command

Tags: linux, bash, shell-scripting, curl

I'm having some hard time finding examples of something relatively simple: At my job, I need to come up with a script to test various servers with curl and then get the outputs in a file.

The command to use is something along 
`$ time curl https://something.net`

I need to run this command in multiple hosts, so here's how the process would look like :

1 - run script from local workstation

2 - script ssh to host 1 and runs curl ---> record the output

3 - script ssh to host 2 and runs curl ---> record the output

4 - etc …

5 - script retrieves all the outputs and writes them to a file in my local host.

What would be the easiest technology to use? examples are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about something like that?

```
#!/bin/bash
url=http://something.net/
hosts=(host1 host2 host3)

for host in "${hosts[@]}"; do
  echo $host
  ssh "$host" -- time curl "$url"
  echo
done
```

still needs to be redirected to a file, but simply iterates over the list of servers and invokes the command there.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, many thanks. I'll accept the answer once tested

Comment: I ended up modifying the script to capture and append to a txt file like this ```#!/bin/bash
url=http://something.net/
hosts=(host1 host2 host3)

for host in "${hosts[@]}"; do
  echo $host >> somefile.txt
  ssh "$host" -- time curl "$url" 2>> somefile.txt
done```